# Windows 11 keeps messing with grub at every restart (+ possible solution?)

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, windows-11, grub

I installed Windows 11 and then Archlinux (I set a dual boot system within the same shared Efi partition).
Everything worked fine for a year or so. But now, whenever windows restarts, it makes grub disappear (at least the entry from the bios boot list) and it remains only the windows bootloader available.

My current config consist on an:

- Efi partition (around 100mb)
- Windows partition
- Linux partition
- Swap etc, etc...

The only way to solve this is to re-install grub again:

1. boot from my USB
2. mount linux root and `efi` partition into `/boot/efi`
3. chroot into my linux partition
4. re-run grub install command and grub-mkconfig:

```bash
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi 
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I was thinking about a solution, but I'm not sure if it could work:

What if I create a boot partition for linux only, install grub there and then tell the bios to boot on that partition. Then add a custom entry on grub that points to the windows bootloader partition, grub should only redirect to windows bootloader.

What do you think, could it work?